# find all images on page with specific url and delete it using java script

Tags: javascript

im trying to find all images on page with a specifc url /images/icons/bollWhiteDown.gif 
and delete or change them can it be done?

and how?

thank you

Answer (score 2):

To remove the IMG tags you can do something like this:

```
var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
    if (imgs[i].getAttribute("src") == "/images/icons/bollWhiteDown.gif") {
        imgs[i].parentNode.removeChild(imgs[i]);
    }
}
```

---

*Based on OP's comment:*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
    var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName("IMG");
    for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {;
        if (imgs[i].getAttribute("src") == "/images/icons/bollWhiteDown.gif") {
            imgs[i].parentNode.removeChild(imgs[i]);
        }
    }
}​
</script>
```

Comment: just a little mistake; `getElementesByTagName("img")` should be `document.getElementsByTagName("img");`

Comment: thank you but for some reason it dosnt work maybe im doing something wrong   <script>
    onload = function () {
        var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
        for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
            if (imgs[i].src == "/images/icons/bollWhiteDown.gif") {
                imgs[i].parentNode.removeChild(imgs[i]);
            }
        }

    }
</script>

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for (var img in images){
   if(images[img].src == '/images/icons/bollWhiteDown.gif'){
      images[img].parentNode.removeChild(images[img])
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
var imgs = document.getElementesByTagName("img");
for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
    if (imgs[i].src == "/images/icons/bollWhiteDown.gif") {
        imgs[i].src = "somethingelse";
    }
}
```

Comment: Please be more specific; do you see any error messages in your browser JavaScript console? I guess you're running the script before DOM gets ready, try putting `script` tag after `body` or wrap it with `window.onload = function() { // write the code here }`